# How to import and use D3-tube-map in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-redux, react-component

I have imported tube-map from d3.js in my reactjs project. But getting the following issue for not importing it properly. The issue I'm getting is shown in below sceenshot:

[image]

Following is the code I'm using. I've installed d3-tube-map using npm. Maybe I'm lacking on properly importing the exported value of d3-tube-map. Any help about this issue?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import d3 from "d3";
import d3 from "d3-tube-map";
import "d3-tip";
import tubeData from "./JSON/tube_data.jsx";

class TubeMap extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var container = d3.select("#tube_map_101");
        var width = 700;
        var height = 400;

        var map = d3
            .tubeMap()
            .width(width)
            .height(height)
            .margin({
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 40,
                left: 100
            })
            .on("click", function(name) {
                console.log(name);
            });

        // d3.json("./stations.json", function (error, data) {
        container.datum(tubeData).call(map);

        var svg = container.select("svg");

        zoom = d3
            .zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.5, 6])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        var zoomContainer = svg.call(zoom);
        var initialScale = 2;
        var initialTranslate = [100, 200];

        zoom.scaleTo(zoomContainer, initialScale);
        zoom.translateTo(
            zoomContainer,
            initialTranslate[0],
            initialTranslate[1]
        );

        function zoomed() {
            svg.select("g").attr("transform", d3.event.transform.toString());
        }
        // });
    }

    render() {
        return <div id="tube_map_101" />;
    }
}

export default TubeMap;
```

Comment: What is the reason of deleting your question from 
 2018-11-16 09:33:17Z https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334987/how-to-import-tubemap-in-react-js-and-use and posting the same question 30 hours later at 2018-11-17 14:35:40Z? This is the 3rd time you post the same question

Comment: Because I wanted a solution and there might be a lack of noticing questions here i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your imports aren't quite right. If you look at the example provided on the [npm page for this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-tube-map), it uses both d3 and d3-tube-map.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/d3-tube-map.js"></script>
```

Which gives a clue, but doesn't help much with how to do this using ES6 imports. Looking at the code for the [module over on github](https://github.com/johnwalley/d3-tube-map), I would try this first (many lines excluded):

```
import tubeMap from "d3-tube-map";

...

    var map = tubeMap()
```

What I noticed on github is that the tubeMap module already imports d3 inside it. So maybe you don't need to import d3 yourself.

If the above doesn't work, you may have to import both d3 and d3-tube-map, in which case I'm not sure how they should work together as imports. If that's the case, I would open an issue on github with the author to get an example.

EDIT: As it turns out, you need to import all the compononents from each module per the code snippet below.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as tubeMap from "d3-tube-map";
import tubeData from "./data/tubeData.jsx";

class TubeMap extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
      d3.tubeMap = tubeMap.tubeMap
      this.renderMap()
    }


    renderMap() {
        var container = d3.select("#tube_map_101");
        var width = 700;
        var height = 400;

        var map = d3
            .tubeMap()
            .width(width)
            .height(height)

etc.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @Todd. I have just tried the first solution which is to import only d3-tube-map and it's causing an error - **d3.tubeMap is not a function** and also tried the second option to import both d3 and d3-tube-map and this case is also causing an error - **Uncaught TypeError: _d2.default.tubeMap is not a function**.

Comment: @Subhojit I'm not sure how to get the imports right, but as your next step you should open an issue at the git repo. In the meantime, if you want to post your code on https://jsfiddle.net/ and add the link to your question, I will be happy to see if I can get it working and update my answer.

Comment: Hi Todd, I've shared the editor url here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9sfz89

Comment: The issue got resolved as I was lacking on importing the attribute from d3-tube-map library properly so I used **import * as tubeMap from 'd3-tube-map'** and the issue got resolved. Thanks @Todd for trying to help.

Comment: This is the working Demo - **https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9sfz89**

Comment: @Subhojit Thanks for following up on this. I added your working code from the link to my answer in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Sure. Good if it helps someone @Todd

Comment: @Subhojit I tried your demo and got `"export 'tubeMap' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'` do you know to fix this? they said it is caused by using v3 syntax for v4 of d3, but i see in the lib he used v5

Comment: @HoàngĐăng check the package.json file of my working demo and match the d3 and tubemap's version with your projects package.json. Here I'm using **"d3": "^5.7.0",
    "d3-tip": "0.9.1",
    "d3-tube-map": "0.6.0"**

Comment: @Subhojit thank for feedback, I get rid of warnings by using this `const d3 = Object.assign(d3Base, { tubeMap.tubeMap });` instead of `d3.tubeMap = tubeMap`

Comment: **Install the exact versions using npm and try out.**

Comment: @Subhojit not even exact version is working anymore with latest react which is v18

Comment: @Felix what is d3Base there. I need to get it working somehow.

Answer (score 0):

With latest version of d3 and d3-tube-map none of the answer works. I tried everything.

**The solution (workaround) is following**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import tubeData from './data';
import './TubeMap.css';

const d3 = require('d3');
const tubeMap = require('d3-tube-map');

export default class TubeMap extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        d3.tubeMap = tubeMap.tubeMap;
        d3.select('#tube-map').html(null);

        this.renderMap();
    }
    renderMap() {

        var container = d3.select('#tube-map');
        var width = 700;
        var height = 700;

        var map = d3.tubeMap()
            .width(width)
            .height(height)
            .margin({
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 40,
                left: 100,
            })
            .on("click", function (name) {
                console.log(name);
            });


        container.datum(tubeData).call(map);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div id="tube-map"></div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Notes**

1. Don't import d3 or d3-tubemap (d3-tip is also useless in this case)
2. Initialize d3 and d3-tubemap with require
3. Add tubeMap to d3 in componentDidMount. I am clearing html because the componentDidMount is called twice